# Изменение выделенной части рисунка с помощью клавиш

Tags: html, css, графика, веб-дизайн, photoshop

С помощью каких **клавиш** можно изменить выделенную часть рисунка (увеличить или уменьшить) в фотошопе и пэйнте (нужны обе эти программы)? Аналог shift + -> (Notepad++). С помощью мыши не удобно - рука дергается (далеко мышью не проведешь).

Comment: Что значит "изменить"?

Comment: @VladimirGonchar увеличить или уменьшить.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar я прояснил вопрос?